# Select correct class that is being clicked with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using a class called container that has a child class in it also. I am using it twice in this example. What I am wondering is how to select it so when you click on one, only that child is shown. If you click on the left box, only the left info is displayed, or if you click on the right box, only the right info is displayed.

Here is the jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/egyckza5/

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">1</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="child">2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    margin:5px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.child{
    color:white;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.child').hide();
});

$('.container').on('click', function(){
    $('.child').show();
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do two things. Use `$(this).find('.child')` to select the relative div:

```
$('.container').on('click', function () {
    $('.child').hide();
    $(this).find('.child').show();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/egyckza5/3/)**

And add `vertical-align:top;` to your container CSS.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('.container').on('click', function(){
    $('.child').hide(); // this is to hide all divs with class child
    $(this).find(".child").show(); //this is to show respective clicked child div
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/egyckza5/2/)**